# Loring Tu Proposition 3.29

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds

In Loring Tu's Introduction to Manifolds, pg. 31, the proof that alternating k-linear functions $\alpha^I$, $I=(i_1 <...<i_k)$ span the space $A_k(V)$ of alternating k-linear functions on $V$ goes like this:

Let $f \in A_k(V)$. Claim that $f=\sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$. Let $g=\sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$. Next show $g(e_J)=f(e_J)$. Therefore $f=g=\sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$.

I'm very confused on why showing $f=g$ implies that $\alpha^I$ spans $A_k(V)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are both defined as $\sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$, it shouldn't be surprising that we find $f=g$. I don't understand why by confirming $f=g$ we prove $\alpha^I$ span $A_k(V)$.

Comment: You are taking an arbitrary $f\in A_k(V)$, and then you define $g=\sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$, it is clear that $g$ is in the span of the $\alpha^I$'s, so if you show that $f=g$, then as $f$ is an arbitrary element of $A_k(V)$, you conclude that that $\alpha^I$'s span $A_k(V)$. Note that you are not defining $f=\sum f(e_I)\alpha^I$ (that is what you are showing)

Comment: The sentence "we claim that $f=$[...]" should be understood as "Lemma: if $f \in A_k$, then $f=$[...]", and the next sentence is a proof of that claim.